# Reducing 3-SAT to Vertex Cover?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, graph-theory, np-complete, satisfiability

Can someone explain to me in the most simplest possible way, how to reduce `3-SAT` to `Vertex Cover` ? I am following the explanation [here](http://web.mit.edu/~neboat/www/6.046-fa09/rec8.pdf)(scroll to page 4 bottom). I understand the basic setup of having two "gadgets": the 2-node variable gadgets and 3-node clause gadgets. I also understand the formula `k = variables + 2 clauses` as the minimum number of nodes required to cover all the edges. What I don't understand is how this set up proves that if there exist a `k-covering`, then the boolean expression in CNF is satisfiable. Examples with expressions that are satisfiable and not satisfiable would be helpful. Also, once the `3-SAT` problem is converted to a `k-covering`, does it provide a means to identify which value( `true` or `false`) should be assigned to each variable so as to satisfy the boolean expression ? Thanks for any help.

Comment: @DmitriChubarovYes. I fixed it.

Comment: The choice of vertex from the corresponding variable gadgets exactly indicates "which value (`true` or `false`) should be assigned to each variable so as to satisfy the boolean expression". ​ Note the "Each literal ... single _additional_ edge ... and variable gadgets." sentence below figure 3. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com